# match by value in a discriminated union, in F#

Tags: f#

with this union:

```
type T =
    | A
    | B
    | C
```

and a *T list*

I would like to implement something like this pseudo code:

```
let countOfType (t: Type) (l: T list) =
    l
    |> List.filter (fun x -> x.GetType() = t)
    |> List.length
```

when I would pass if I want to count the 'A', 'B', etc..
but A.GetType() and B.GetType() return the T type, so this doesn't work.

Is there a way where I could check the type by passing it as a parameter?

The practical case here is that I have a Map that gets updated every few seconds and its values are part of the same DU. I need to be able to see how many of each type, without having to update the code (like a match block) each time an entry gets added.

---

Addendum:
I simplified the original question too much and realized it after seeing Fyodor's answer.

So I would like to add the additional part:
how could this also be done for cases like these:

```
type T =
    | A of int
    | B of string
    | C of SomeOtherType
```

Comment: "I need to be able to see how many of each type each time an entry gets added": you can persist the counts and increment the appropriate one when you add.  But do you count all cases each time or just the case that matches the item being added?

Comment: I thought about that, but since we're doing live tests and the code changes a lot, I'd rather not have to update various pieces of code to keep variables up to date. The reason I'd like to implement it that way is that, even if it's not the faster thing, the logic would be contained in a single place.

Comment: I've been meaning to write an answer to this and now that I've sat down to do so, it seems that the premise is flawed.  With `type T = A of int | B of string | C of float;; List.map (fun x -> x.GetType().Name) [A 1; B "Two"; C 3.0]`, I get as the result `["A"; "B"; "C"]`.  Perhaps this is an implementation detail.  What version of F# are you using?

Comment: How are you calling `countOfType`?  It looks like the problem is probably actually obtaining a reference to the `A`, `B`, or `C` type, as there doesn't seem to be a way to do that in F# without an instance (or using reflection).

Comment: @Phoog, I had to resort to pattern matching, I couldn't find another good way

Comment: Hm, well given that `GetType()` does actually return distinct types for each case, I think you misdiagnosed the problem.  But there are also some instance methods that are hidden by the F# compiler that could help, which is what I was planning to base my answer on.  Still, for "how many of each type," how do you denote the type?  In what form do you want the result?  In F#, `T.A` is a function, which is what makes it difficult.  (The problem with pattern matching, of course, is that you have to modify the pattern matching code whenever you add or remove cases.)

Comment: what I need is a sum of each type, as a n-tuple

Answer (score 1):

Try `List.choose: ('a -> 'b option) -> 'a list -> 'b list`, it filters list based on `'a -> 'b option` selector. If selectors evaluates to `Some`, then value will be included, if selector evaluates to `None`, then value will be skipped. If you worry about allocations caused by instantiation of `Some`, then you'll have to implement version that will use `ValueOption`

```ml
    let onlyA lis =
        lis |> List.choose (function
                            | (A _) as a -> Some a
                            | _ -> None)

    let onlyB lis =
        lis |> List.choose (function
                            | (B _) as b -> Some b
                            | _ -> None)
    let lis = [
        A 1
        A 22
        A 333
        B ""
        B "123"
    ]

    lis |> onlyA |> List.length |> printfn "%d"
```

Answer (score 0):

For such enum type `T` as you specified, you can just use regular comparison:

```
let countOfType t (l: T list) =
    l
    |> List.filter (fun x -> x = t)
    |> List.length
```

Usage:

```
> countOfType A [A; A; B; C; A]
3

> countOfType B [A; A; B; C; A]
1
```

Comment: unfortunately your answer made me realize that I made a mistake and simplified the question too much: in my case those are | A of xxx | B of xxx types. I'll edit the question to cover both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can pattern match, and throw away the data, to create a function for the filter.

```
type T =
| A of int
| B of string
| C of float

[A 3;A 1;B "foo";B "bar";C 3.1; C 4.6]
|> List.filter (fun x -> 
    match x with
    | A _ -> true
    | B _ -> false
    | C _ -> false
)
|> List.length
```

But in general i would asume, that you create a predicate function in your modul.

```
let isA x =
    match x with
    | A _ -> true
    | _   -> false
```

if you have those functions you can just write

```
[A 3;A 1;B "foo";B "bar";C 3.1; C 4.6]
|> List.filter isA
|> List.length
```